# Is every linear transformation by orthogonal matrixes are rotate transform?

Tags: linear-algebra

orthogonal matrixes conserve length of every vector and scalar products of them, I think only rotate transformation satisfy those property, but I don't know how to prove it, whether it's true or not.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not true. For example, $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}$ is orthogonal, but it’s not a rotation.

Rotations have a determinant of $1$, but orthogonal matrices in general can have a determinant of $\pm1$. In the plane, the orthogonal transformations with determinant $-1$ are all reflections, but that’s not true in higher dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's restrict your notion of matrices to finite-dimensional vector spaces. Consider the definition of an isometry (distance preserving function). 
$$\|(F(x)\| = \|x\|$$ So clearly our notion of orthogonal matrices are finite-dimensional, linear, isometries. In other words, they are rotations, reflections, and a combination of both. For more general information I suggest you learn about *[orthogonal groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group)*. Cheers.